${}$Is this constraint holonomic or non-holonomic?

Consider a velocity-dependent constraint, $$A\dot{x}+B=0$$ where $A$ and $B$ are two constants and $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Is this constraint holonomic or non-holonomic for any arbitrary $A$ and $B ?$

I am getting the answer as holonomic because the differential equation given here is integrable. But one of my friend is insisting that the answer is non-holonomic and to be honest I can't understand his explanation for the same.
Can anyone confirm what the answer really is? Any help is greatly appreciated.

your constraint equation
$$ A\,\frac{dx}{dt}+B=0 $$
integrate
$$A\,x+B\,t=0 $$
this constraint equation is call scleronomic constraint $~Q=Q(x,t)=0~$

From Wikipedia (simplified)

For a constraint to be holonomic it must be expressible as a function:
$$f([x],t)=0,$$
i.e. a holonomic constraint depends only on the coordinate [$x$] and maybe time $t$. It does not depend on the velocities or any higher-order derivative with respect to $t$. A constraint that cannot be expressed in the form shown above is a nonholonomic constraint.

Since the constraint you are interested in is dependent on the velocity $\dot x$ it is nonholonomic.
EDIT: As @Eli pointed out, the constraint can be easily integrated into a holonomic constraint.

As you can see from @Eli's answer, the constraint in the question can be recast into the form $f([x],t)=0.$

True, I stand corrected.

If a velocity constraint can be integrated to a position constraint, it is generally called holonomic.  It is only nonholonomic if it CAN'T be integrated.

Is it though? Identifying integrability can be very hard sometimes, especially in higher dimensions. Of course it is just a matter of definition, but it feels very cumbersome to me, if you can't call a constraint nonholonomic without proving non-integrability first.
